# Multiple occurrences of a field based on another field

Tags: sql, multiple-entries

I have a table Accounts which is having various fields. Out of which I want three fields **acct_nbr**, **Acct_Indicator1**, **Acct_Indicator2**.  I want to find those **accounts which are having multiple values for Acct_Indicator1 and Acct_Indicator2**. Below is the query I have used. Please let me know the correct version :

```
SELECT acct_nbr, Acct_Indicator1, Acct_Indicator2 
FROM table1
GROUP BY acct_nbr, Acct_Indicator1, Acct_Indicator2
ORDER BY acct_nbr
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try this using `in` for `Acct_Indicator1` and `Acct_Indicator2`

```
SELECT acct_nbr
    ,Acct_Indicator1
    ,Acct_Indicator2
FROM table1
WHERE Accnt_Indicator1 IN (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN count(Accnt_Indicator1) > 1
                    THEN Accnt_Indicator1
                END AS col1
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY acct_nbr
        )
    AND Accnt_Indicator2 IN (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN count(Accnt_Indicator2) > 1
                    THEN Accnt_Indicator2
                END AS col2
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY acct_nbr
        )
GROUP BY acct_nbr
    ,Acct_Indicator1
    ,Acct_Indicator2
ORDER BY acct_nbr
```